# What is the maximum length of the "to" list in the Mailgun's sending email API?

Tags: python, mailgun

I use a Python method below to send email to our clients with Mailgun's [Sending via API](https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#sending-via-api):

```
def send_simple_message():
    return requests.post(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages",
        auth=("api", "YOUR_API_KEY"),
        data={"from": "Excited User <mailgun@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>",
              "to": my_clients,
              "subject": "Hello",
              "text": "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!"})
```

When the length of `my_clients` in the "data" is less than 20, the method return `<Response [200]`, and the mail is delivered successfully. However, when the length grows to 6000+, it returns `<Response [400]>`, and clients can't receive the mail.

So what is the maximum length of this list? I searched the docs and googled, but found nothing.
What's the recommended way when the quantity of clients is larger than this limit? Divide the clients into several groups and call this method for each group?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The max is 1000 recipients:

https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#batch-sending

Send in chunks of 1000 recipients per email.